# String manipulation using programming language c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like below

```
"177848,183074,184225,182439,21002,186745,186615,186362,188001,189777,190224,189535,190629,104602,183314,190203,190341,191050,188027,190003,158104,188564,129725,179936,189696,57340,190906,46815,185009,181315,179967,186804,181993"
```

I would like to make a bunch of 5 like this.

```
"177848,183074,184225,182439,21002"
"186745,186615,186362,188001,189777"
"190224,189535,190629,104602,183314"
"190203,190341,191050,188027,190003"
"158104,188564,129725,179936,189696"
"57340,190906,46815,185009,181315"
"179967,186804,181993"
```

I can do this using foreach then set a limit.
but want minimum line of code to do this
programming language is c#

```
   IList<int> list = new List<int>() { 177848, 183074, 184225, 182439, 21002, 186745, 186615, 186362, 188001, 189777, 190224, 189535, 190629, 104602, 
            183314, 190203, 190341, 191050, 188027, 190003, 158104, 188564, 129725, 179936, 189696, 57340, 190906, 46815, 185009, 181315, 179967, 186804,
            181993 };
        int batchSize = 5;
        int length = Math.Abs(list.Count() / batchSize) + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            IEnumerable<int> list1 = list.Skip(i * batchSize).Take(batchSize);
        }
```

Comment: use StringBuilder and a foreach loop

Comment: Minimum amount of lines:  `string[] lines = new string[7] {"177848,183074,184225,182439,21002", "186745,186615,186362,188001,189777", "190224,189535,190629,104602,183314", "190203,190341,191050,188027,190003", "158104,188564,129725,179936,189696", "57340,190906,46815,185009,181315", "179967,186804,181993"};`  |=^]

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                IEnumerable<int> list1 = list.Skip(i * batchSize).Take(batchSize);

            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex.

```
string text = "177848,183074,184225,182439,21002,186745,186615,186362,188001,189777,190224,189535,190629,104602,183314,190203,190341,191050,188027,190003,158104,188564,129725,179936,189696,57340,190906,46815,185009,181315,179967,186804,181993";
string[] lines = Regex.Matches(text, "([^,]+,){1,4}[^,]+")
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(m => m.Value)
                      .ToArray();
```

Or another way with regex:

```
string text = "177848,183074,184225,182439,21002,186745,186615,186362,188001,189777,190224,189535,190629,104602,183314,190203,190341,191050,188027,190003,158104,188564,129725,179936,189696,57340,190906,46815,185009,181315,179967,186804,181993";
string[] lines = Regex.Split(text, "(?<=^(?:[^,]*,){4}[^,]*(?:(?:,[^,]*){5})*),");
```

Comment: I was getting to that but you beat me to it.

Comment: Don't answer a question where the OP doesn't show what he/she has tried.  It encourages laziness.

Comment: Regex is overkil for something that is simply comma-seaprated.

Comment: Thanks CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc... pls check the code now

Answer (score 0):

Replace every fifth ',' with a '\n' using Regex.